# Is the "PROB" in a TAF only applying to the next group or all following ones?

Tags: terminology, meteorology, taf

Let's assume I have a TAF that reads:

```
[...]
PROB40
TEMPO 0815/0822 5000 -SHSN BKN008 OVC015
TEMPO 0822/0909 1000 SN VV003
BECMG 0902/0904 16012KT
```

Which of the `TEMPO` / `BECMG` groups have a probability of 40%? All three because everything that follows `PROB40` has a probability of 40%? Just the first `TEMPO` because `PROB40` only means the one following line in the TAF? Or both `TEMPO` ones, and `BECMG` is again certain and not just 40% probable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PROB40 is targeted only on the immediate TEMPO group. If there are several PROB/TEMPOs both keywords must be repeated every time. Also, PROB is never associated with BECMG or FM groups, which indicate permanent change.

Comment: Welcome to Av.SE -- nice answer.